log4j2 same policy for logging into multiple files using log4j2.properties file
I am modifying existing log4j2.properties file to log error into a separate file. My question is how can i REUSE SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy and DefaultRolloverStrategy for multiple fileappenders. I dont want to copy same stuff multiple times
appender.errorfile.policies.type=Policies
appender.errorfile.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorfile.policies.size.size = 51200KB
appender.errorfile.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorfile.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.errorfile.policies.time.modulate = true

appender.errorfile.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.errorfile.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.errorfile.strategy.delete.basePath = /logs
appender.errorfile.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.errorfile.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.errorfile.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age=30d
appender.errorfile.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.errorfile.filter.threshold.level = ERROR
appender.errorfile.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.errorfile.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY


appender.errorfile.type=RollingFile
appender.errorfile.name=File-ERROR
appender.errorfile.fileName=/logs/error.log
appender.errorfile.filePattern=/logs/error_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.errorfile.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.errorfile.layout.pattern=%d %-5p [%C] (%tn) %m (%F:%L)%n



Can you explain what is your end goal? You want to have a separate log file per log level?

i want error log level to go into separate file and others into main log file

There is no way to reuse parts of a properties file or to compose multiple properties file into one.
The only configuration format that allows it is XML, through the built-in XInclude functionality. Therefore you can create a template file rolling-file.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RollingFile>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="51200 KB"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="logs" maxDepth="10">
            <IfLastModified age="30d"/>
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>

and include parts of it in a log4j2.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="File-ERROR"
                     fileName="logs/error.log"
                     filePattern="logs/error_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%C] (%tn) %m (%F:%L)%n"/>
            <xi:include href="rolling-file.xml" xpointer="element(/1/1)"/>
            <xi:include href="rolling-file.xml" xpointer="element(/1/2)"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    ...
</Configuration>

If the configuration of your other appenders is similar (e.g. they differ only by name), you can use RoutingAppender.
